# Automatically redirect to the PREVIOUS BROWSED page

Tags: php

I have read some stackoverflow hyperlinks about *how to redirect to the previous browsed page* after a user logs in or creates a new post in a forum. I have found that most of the answers mentioned about using `AJAX` or `javascript` or the like, because most of the answerers think that it should only happen on the client side. Furthermore, most of their codes provided helpfully advised how to redirect to a **certain** page like **index.php** after log-in.

For me, what i really want to do now is how to redirect to the **previous browsed/visited page** after clicking the **submit** button of the form by using **PHP** **(PLEASE FORGET ABOUT AJAX OR JAVASCRIPT NOW)**. I **don't** redirect users to any certain assigned page, but **to the page immediately before it**. For example, a user visits the `index.php`, then clicks a hyperlink on it to go to the `posts.php` page to view the new posts, and then he's interested in the forum, he then goes to the `login.php` page from the `http://domain.com/posts.php?qid=7`, for instance, to sign in so that he can reply to the post if he wants to or does something else. In this scenario, after he logs in, the forum would `*REDIRECT* him to the immediately previous posts.php page`, which is `http://domain.com/posts.php?qid=7`. That is what I want to code now.

And this is the function I just created:

```
    function str_url($a, $b) { 
     return substr($a, 0, strpos($a, $b));
    }

    function self_url() {
    if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }else{
    $self = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    $secure = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s":"";
    $protocol_secure = str_url(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$secure;
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
    $_SESSION['previous'] = $protocol_secure."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$self;

    header("Location: " . $_SESSION['previous']);
    }
```

All I have to do is to place the functions in the head of the document and the  `self_url();` anywhere within the PHP code after the `form checking and submission` conditionals that I want.

The problem is that the function `self_url();` just checks the `domain.com/posts.php` to redirect the logged-in users to (*it truncates the rest part of the URL*), but not the whole long URL of the previously visited page like `http://domain.com/posts.php?qid=7` (in which the `id=7` is the `name=value` pair of a certain post) he just visited before he signed in.

Can you help me to isolate the reason, please? Or *If you have any handy PHP function to replace mine, I'll appreciate it*.

Answer (score 1):

The previous URL *might* be visible to you via `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` so you could just take this as your redirection target. But this is not very reliable - from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'HTTP_REFERER'
>
> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. **Not all user agents
>   will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as
>   a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.**

The better approach would be to let the previous script insert a GET parameter of itself so your redirection script knows where the user was before.

Well, you could store every visited page a cookie or session and just read it from there but that doesn't make much sense in my opinion.

//edit some code:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
}else{
    $self = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Just append `?redir=$self` to the action of your form.

Comment: That's the reason why I dont want to use the `'HTTP_REFERER'` and created my own function in PHP.

Comment: Well, you could store every visited page a cookie or session and just read it from there but that doesn't make much sense in my opinion. 

Otherwise it is not possible for a script to know where the user has been before.